# Damaging BCD-to-decimal decoders?

Tags: integrated-circuit, high-voltage, nixie

(ACTUAL QUESTION IS AT THE BOTTOM)

I am a beginner in electronics and am learning more day-by-day to my best. I first got interested in Nixie tubes a few years back, so those are what I play around with, as they sparkef my curiosity.

I have been using this circuit I came up with:

[image]

And it has been working fine; all five 74141's I have had been working until late.

But I have found that, for some reason, when I had started using some new breadboard I had bought, that, suddenly, the circuit did not work. I removed it all and put it back together on my old breadboard and found that it did the same; all of the digits would be lit up at the same time save for one or two and would barely flicker. I did not think to swap out the 74141 for some of the other ones I havhavbut instead I decided to swap the tube for some LED's as I have before done using the same layout; all of the anodes connected together, sharing one common resistor:

[image]

It was at this point I saw that a handful of the LED's barely lit, others cycled through my test program, but LED #6, on pin 10 of the 74141 stayed on no matter what. Frustrated, I undid the entire circuit and redid it still the same thing. I have no idea why, but I decided to swap out the 74141 for another; it works perfectly; testing both multiplexing and just normal half-second cycle through, as should be expected.

QUESTION:

Exposition out of the way, IS THERE ANY WAY I COULD HAVE DAMAGED IT WITH MY CIRCUIT? Or perhaps just something random with the IC itself; it's not old (it's datecode is 1540--fortieth week of the 2015.) Some are still producing the K155ID1 in Russia for some reason. Perhaps dropping it? Or accidentally swapping the VCC and GND for it?

Comment: Why are you using a BCD decoder at all? you have a full microcontroller, which could trivially be programmed to know that, for example, `8` means "enable all seven segments".

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ah youngsters. The Nixie is a fat round iphone screen that only displays one digit at a time in orange, and has a separate wire for each possible digit. Next weeks episode: Mr Baudots mechanical twitter machines

Comment: By the way, excellent debugging. (you should, though, add a resistor to every single LED: else, the more LEDs you turn on, the less bright the individual LED becomes.

Comment: Also, make sure that you've read the datasheet of your IC! There's a hard limit on how much current you might sink into each pin, and I'm not sure your LED setup respects that (and yes, you can damage an IC with that).

Comment: If you accidentally shorted the 180V or the anode to the output pins, it probably wouldn't like it. My nixie driver only needs 60V transistors, 74141s might have a fairly low voltage capability too. (but I don't know much about them)

Comment: @HenryCrun LoL "a fat, round iPhone screen..." It's accurate. On a separate note, what do you think of using only one 74141 to drive 2 or more tubes and just using a transistor to turn the tube anodes high or low?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Indeed; I shall double check, and that is interesting. And I do say, thank you for the compliment on the debugging; that actually made my day, I'd say.

Comment: If you select any of the values A-F, then none of the electrodes is selected, and it is possible to get a higher voltage on the outputs than the rated 60V max depending on leakage currents. The datasheet does say you can use these values for blanking, but perhaps it can damage them? My circuits have clamps to prevent this. (again I have no experience of this chip)

Comment: I have seen something on the webs of it being done, with traces showing the required inter-digit times. It was never done back in the day. Nixies (and neons) are slowly worn out by (normal) current. I suspect that a muxed arrangement would result in shorter lifetime for the same average current, if that matters to you.

Comment: @HenryCrun Thank you again; longer or shorter life; I am sure it wouldn't be too major, but that is important to note--longer life is better. Hmm... I am afraid I do not understand what blanking is? I am incredibly new to this and learning independently to the best I can.

Comment: What value did you use for R2?

Comment: @MartinF I have just been using 10k; 20k might be more appropriate.

Comment: Allright. Yeah, it might be on the low side, but it depends on the type of Nixie you have of course. If this is what your Nixies need, then you're allright. Besides, I think, if you've used 10k, then that's probably not the reason why your 74141 blew. Just checking :-)

Comment: The 180V is DC, right? How do you 'generate' the 180VDC, is that working properly? Maybe consider tying the GND of the 180VDC supply straight to the GND of the 74141, instead of running it through the Arduino?

Comment: @MartinF I actually do ground it straight to the 74141 usually; in the schematic, I did ground it to the Arduino, though. As for how I generate the 180V, I use a 12v-180v dc-to-dc boost converter.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested that you can just use npn transistors. This arrangement lets you use 7 pins to drive all 10 nixie digits. Off bases must be driven low. On a pcb, this is just 5 dual BC846 transistor packages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAwuE5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is possible to drive 10 digits with only 6 pins, but 6 resistors are needed.

ignore(i.stack.imgur.com/2vAjU.png)

Comment: You can even use MPSA41s which are cheap and are rated for 300V so you can turn any tube off completely (for blanking leading zeros, for example).

Comment: Indeed. Using a high voltage transistor should allow 4 pins to control all 10 digits. Interesting that they have really low min gains (25@1mA). xx5551's (VCE=160V) seem more normal (80@10mA)